# Dompdf generating pdf very slow when I use it with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I got an html file. When I used dompdf "standalone" (no laravel there) (I mean only install dompdf via composer), it works as fast as it can (generate 50kb html + a lot of images there for 5 seconds only). But when I installed dompdf on my laravel app and adjusted my html to blade template, it working much slower (same html rendered for 40-50 seconds!!!). This depends on the images, when I got no images in my html template, it works fine.

Rendering images with blade and paths like this: `{{public_path('pdf/img/12345.jpg')}}`. What should I do to avoid this problem?

My controller's code is:

```
public function create(Request $request) {
    $pdf = new Dompdf();
    $html = View::make('pdf.template')->render();        
    $pdf->loadHtml($html, 'UTF-8');
    $pdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
    $pdf->render();
    $filename = "Hi!";
    return $pdf->stream($filename, ["Attachment" => false]);
}
```

But `dd($html)` works very fast, and I dont understand, why images makes rendering so slow on laravel app, but it works fine on standalone app.

Comment: Do you do any database queries by any chance? Show the view code.

Comment: @Kyslik no, I didn't, but db queries will be added soon. The view code is too long to past it to question, post it on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v8q2t3dj/

Comment: I should say that without pictures it works much faster

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap is the cause of this, or similar with a lot of css classes.

More details, and why, can be found here:
[Slow PDF generation with PHP+DomPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54768375/slow-pdf-generation-with-phpdompdf)

Comment: Please don't link to another Stack Overflow answer when it is an answer the question. Instead, vote to close the question as duplicate.