# Adding CSS Into Dompdf Library in Codeignator

Tags: css, codeigniter, bootstrap-4, dompdf

I'm able to generate PDF file from Codeigniter Framework using Dompdf library but the pdf generated it doesn't have the style that I used on creating the page, how can I add CSS to be rendered together with HTML

My function that creates a PDF looks like

```
function generateReport($id = null){
 $this->load->library('pdf');

    $data['title'] = 'Student Report';
    $details = $this->student_model->get_single_student($id);
    $result = $this->student_model->get_single_student_result($id);
    $data['student'] = $details;
    $data['result'] = $result;
    $filename = $data['student']['admission_no'];
  $this->pdf->load_view('admin/mark/singleMarkShow', $data);
  $this->pdf->render();
  $this->pdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
 }
```

This is PDF Genarated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSSoc.png)

And my HTML Page which I create to export pdf is like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUthw.png)

Comment: DOMPDF is DOMPDF. The framework (Codeigniter) is wholly irrelevant here. Also, please show us what you have done with a minimum code necessary to replicate/understand the issue

Comment: it's not entirely irrelevant, actually, since the Codeigniter+DomPDF integration has some quirks that may in fact be causing the OP's issue (such as the way the CSS files are linked). I do agree that the view code is missing though

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try something like this, hopes it help you.

$pdf = new Dompdf();
$html = "<div>PDF content...</div>";
$html .= '<link type="text/css" href="/give/path/of/pdffile.css" rel="stylesheet" />';
$pdf->loadHtml($html);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with DomPDF in more ways than one, so I know how confused you might be.

You're not showing the code for your view (`'admin/mark/singleMarkShow'`) but if you need to have CSS styling you have basically two choices:

1.- You may link the CSS file in the view in almost the same way that you would on any HTML file (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="file.css">` BUT you need to **enter a full absolute path to the CSS file, not a relative one**. Hence, your href should be something along the lines of `FCPATH./assets/css/style.css`
Keep in mind that using huge CSS files such as bootstrap will cause DomPDF to slow down A LOT (see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54768375/slow-pdf-generation-with-phpdompdf) for details)

2.- You may inline your required styles in the view. Just use the styles you need (to reduce overhead) like you would on any html file such as:

```
<style>
body {
  font-size: 11px;
}

small {
  font-size: 65%;
}
(...)
</style>
```

This will allow much faster rendering, with the cost of needing to update all the views you use to create PDF files separately in case of a redesign.

Also, regardless of what choice you make, remember that domPDF expects absolute paths for everything, so even for images you'd need your `src` attributes to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or `FCPATH` plus the rest of the route relative from the main  `index.php` file